# How to remove dictionary keys before a specific one (in insertion order)?

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a **dictionary**

```
dic = {
    'aa': 10,
    'bb': 11,
    'cc': 12,
    'dd': 13,
    'ee': 14,
    'ff': 15,
}
```

How to remove the specified key - let's say **'cc': 12**, and all the keys before it (in order of insertion)?

I need to get the following in my dictionary

```
'dd': 13
'ee': 14
'ff': 15
```

**PS.** *I didn’t think that such a simple task required any additional clarification. But now (based on the responses) I see that there are some nuances.*

Since the answers have already been received I can not edit the original question, otherwise the integrity of the context will be broken. However, the user [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128332/how-to-remove-dictionary-keys-before-a-specific-one-in-insertion-order/77128381?noredirect=1#comment135989444_77128381) proposed to consider this question on the example of the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'zz': 10, 'yy': 11, 'cc': 12, 'dd': 13, 'aa': 14, 'ff': 15}
```

with the expected result:

```
'dd': 13, 'aa': 14, 'ff': 15
```

See **answers** and **comments** for more details

Comment: Probably easier to create a _new_ dictionary that has only the keys you want to keep, instead of actually removing.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok, but how?

Comment: Probably worth clarifying what you mean by "above it". Lexicographic order? Insertion order?

Comment: Why all those ugly unnecessary backslashes?

Comment: @KellyBundy For more readability. The backslashes is not required indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to consider the order of the keys (python ≥ 3.6), you can use a simple loop:

```
for k in list(dic):
    dic.pop(k)
    if k == 'cc':
        break
print(dic)
```

If you don't want to remove anything if the key is absent:

```
target = 'cc'
if target in dic:
    for k in list(dic):
        dic.pop(k)
        if k == target:
            break
```

Output: `{'dd': 13, 'ee': 14, 'ff': 15}`

Alternative with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html) that creates a new dictionary:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, islice

out = {k: dic[k] for k in islice(dropwhile(lambda x: x!='cc', dic), 1, None)}
```

Comment: With such a simple dictionary, other posters' answers solve the problem. But your version with **itertools** helps to cope even with complex long dictionaries. When you need to preserve the insertion order of an old dictionary in a new one. You are the best!

Comment: @Michael you're welcome, the question should be edited to clarify that insertion order was the desired parameter. John's answer would have been valid (and mine not) if lexicographic order was desired. With insertion order it's the other way around.

Comment: You might also want to change `aa` to `zz` in the example to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, now the question itself and the answers to it have become 2 times more useful for the stackers' community. Because it is suitable for simple and complex cases at the same time.

Comment: As for `pp` and `zz`, I don’t quite understand how these letters can show the importance of preserving the insertion order. Now, for ease of understanding, the simplest dictionary is given. And since people more often work with base 10 than with hexadecimal digits, when they read the question they will remember their meanings again.

Comment: Using `dic = {'zz': 10, 'yy': 11, 'cc': 12, 'dd': 13, 'aa': 14, 'ff': 15}` as input would make it unambiguous that the expected output `{'dd': 13, 'aa': 14, 'ff': 15}` is due to insertion order and not lexicographic order (for which the output would be `{'zz': 10, 'yy': 11, 'dd': 13, 'ff': 15}`). This better shows what you **don't want**. Currently both logics give the same (ambiguous) result.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easier to create a new dictionary that has only the keys you want to keep, instead of actually removing.

The Pythonic way to do that is a dict comprehension:

```
newdict = {k:v for k,v in olddict.items() if k > 'cc'}
```

But even if you weren't aware of that syntax, you could use a simple for loop:

```
newdict = {}
for key in olddict:
    if key > 'cc':
        newdict[key] = olddict[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `collections.OrderedDict()` and its [`popitem(last)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) method to facilitate popping from the beginning, since you are essentially treating the dictionary as an ordered container (queue or stack).

```py
import collections

dic = { \
    'aa': 10, \
    'bb': 11, \
    'cc': 12, \
    'dd': 13, \
    'ee': 14, \
    'ff': 15, \
}

odic = collections.OrderedDict(dic)
print(f"Before popUntil(): {odic = }")

def popUntil(odic, target_key):
    while target_key in odic:
        odic.popitem(last=False)

popUntil(odic, "cc")

print(f"After popUntil(): {odic = }")
```

Setting `last=False` in `popitem()` will pop items from the beginning.